# Example of a power series whose function has a finite limit at a point where the series diverges

Tags: limits, continuity, power-series

Let $\Sigma_n a_nz^n$ be a power series with convergence radius $R\in\mathbb R^*_+$ and say there exists $l$ such that $\Sigma_n a_nz^n \rightarrow l$ when $z\rightarrow R$. I believe that it is not necessary for $\Sigma_n a_nR^n$ to converge (or at least towards $l$ ?). Does anyone have an example ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the series $f(z)=\sum_{n}z^n$. For $z$ in the disc of convergence, we have $f(z)=\frac{1}{1-z}$. Therefore, for $z\to-1$ we have $f(z)\to\frac{1}{2}$.

However, $\sum_{n}(-1)^n$ doesn't converge.

---

Heads up.

This exercise is preparing you for further results in which the answer is yes, but more requirements are asked from the power series. See, for example, [Littlewood's Tauberian theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Littlewood%27s_Tauberian_theorem).